# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'matplotlib' but can import it in terminal

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, raspberry-pi, pycharm

Whenever I try to load matplotlib or NumPy I get this error in the console:

```
(import matplotlib.pyplot as plt) :

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/opt/pycharm-community-2019.3.1/plugins/python-ce/helpers/pydev/_pydev_bundle/pydev_umd.py", line 197, in runfile
    pydev_imports.execfile(filename, global_vars, local_vars)  # execute the script
  File "/opt/pycharm-community-2019.3.1/plugins/python-ce/helpers/pydev/_pydev_imps/_pydev_execfile.py", line 18, in execfile
    exec(compile(contents+"\n", file, 'exec'), glob, loc)
  File "/home/pi/PycharmProjects/Cluster Algo 1/cluster 1.py", line 1, in <module>
    import matplotlib
  File "/opt/pycharm-community-2019.3.1/plugins/python-ce/helpers/pydev/_pydev_bundle/pydev_import_hook.py", line 21, in do_import
    module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'matplotlib'

for NumPy (import numpy as np) :

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/opt/pycharm-community-2019.3.1/plugins/python-ce/helpers/pydev/_pydev_bundle/pydev_umd.py", line 197, in runfile
    pydev_imports.execfile(filename, global_vars, local_vars)  # execute the script
  File "/opt/pycharm-community-2019.3.1/plugins/python-ce/helpers/pydev/_pydev_imps/_pydev_execfile.py", line 18, in execfile
    exec(compile(contents+"\n", file, 'exec'), glob, loc)
  File "/home/pi/PycharmProjects/Cluster Algo 1/cluster 1.py", line 7, in <module>
    import numpy as np
  File "/opt/pycharm-community-2019.3.1/plugins/python-ce/helpers/pydev/_pydev_bundle/pydev_import_hook.py", line 21, in do_import
    module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy
```

I'm not sure if I tried `pip install matplotlib` before; I tried `pip3 install matplotlib` and was successful. NumPy installation wasn't successful at first, but I could install it with the command `sudo -k pip3 install`. I also tried a method where it seems to install python 2.7 or something. I have python 2.7 and 3.8 on my machine. One time I re-installed it and the terminal told me I should upgrade my python 2.7.

I uninstalled it and tried re-installing it, but pycharm doesn't import the library. Right now if I try to uninstall it, it will tell me there is nothing to uninstall. I can still load it up in python terminal, but can't load it up on pycharm.

If I load up a terminal (Windows and Linux) and type `import matplotlib` or `NumPy`, I do not receive any error. I only receive an import error while I'm on Pycharm.

Comment: in python terminal if I type the following :
help("modules") i get the following before the modules list :

 "You should import from ipykernel or jupyter_client instead.", ShimWarning)
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/mpl_toolkits/axes_grid/__init__.py:12: MatplotlibDeprecationWarning: 
The mpl_toolkits.axes_grid module was deprecated in Matplotlib 2.1 and will be removed two minor releases later. Use mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1 and mpl_toolkits.axisartist, which provide the same functionality instead.
  obj_type='module')

Comment: Please check that these packages are installed on interpreter specified in File - Settings - Project - Project Interpreter